# TabGroup Activity problem in android

Tags: android

i have TabAvtivity, in which under particular Tab i have  a single Tab GroupActivity ,under this group i have 3 activities. here is the below format.

TabActivity-->Tab1 Tab2 Tab3

under Tab2 --> TabGroupActivity.

under TabGroupActivity--> Activiy1 --> Activity 2 --> Activity 3.

the problem is under TabGroupActivity if i select **Activity 2 from Activity 1** . and when i **press back from Activity 2**. the Activity 1 is restarting. i dont want this to be happened. same with Activity 2 and three

here is my TabGroupActivity

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

        private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

        static boolean restartFlag=false;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        /**
        * This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method.
        * This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child activity
        * and starts the previous activity.
        * If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
        * calls finish to finish the entire group.
        */
        @Override
        public void finishFromChild(Activity child) 
        {
            restartFlag=true;

            Log.e("finishFromChild","finishFromChild");
            LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();

            int index = mIdList.size()-1;

            if (index < 1) {

                finish();

                return;
            }

            //manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);

            mIdList.remove(index);

            index--;

            String lastId = mIdList.get(index);

            Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();

            Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

            setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());

        }

        /**
        * Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
        * @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
        * @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
        * @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
        *///Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP

        public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {

            Window window;
            Log.e("startChildActivity","startChildActivity");

                window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP ));

                if (window != null) 
                {
                    mIdList.add(Id);

                    setContentView(window.getDecorView());
                }


        }

        /**
        * The primary purpose is to prevent systems before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
        * from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
        */
        /*@Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {

            //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        *//**
        * Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
        * so that all systems call onBackPressed().
        *//*
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }*/

        /**
        * If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
        * Simply override and add this method.
        */
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed () 
        {

            Log.e("onBackPressed","Back Came Here");

            int length = mIdList.size();

            Log.d("onBackPressed",String.valueOf(length));

            if ( length >= 1) 
            {
                Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
                current.finish();
            }

         }
}
```

Comment: I am using this same class and can't have the previous activity restarted when a child is destroyed.  If you've found a solution, please post it.

Comment: HI E-Madd i have added my solution in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330029/in-activitygroup-how-to-restore-the-previous-activitywithout-restarting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ E-Madd

here i will post the answer. the actual problem was with destroy() method of ActivityGroup (which is a bug),  so use this custom destroy method to solve the problem.

```
           public boolean destroy(String id , LocalActivityManager manager) {

    if(manager != null){
        manager.destroyActivity(id, false);
        try {
            final Field mActivitiesField = LocalActivityManager.class.getDeclaredField("mActivities");
            if(mActivitiesField != null){
                mActivitiesField.setAccessible(true);
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final Map<String, Object> mActivities = (Map<String, Object>)mActivitiesField.get(manager);
                if(mActivities != null){
                    mActivities.remove(id);
                }
                final Field mActivityArrayField = LocalActivityManager.class.getDeclaredField("mActivityArray");
                if(mActivityArrayField != null){
                    mActivityArrayField.setAccessible(true);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final ArrayList<Object> mActivityArray = (ArrayList<Object>)mActivityArrayField.get(manager);
                    if(mActivityArray != null){
                        for(Object record : mActivityArray){
                            final Field idField = record.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
                            if(idField != null){
                                idField.setAccessible(true);
                                final String _id = (String)idField.get(record);
                                if(id.equals(_id)){
                                    mActivityArray.remove(record);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and also paste this below line

```
          Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

**and dont add any flags while starting the activity.** and also you can refer this link for more info  [destroyActivity() Bug in LocalActivityManager class in Android issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463203/destroyactivity-bug-in-localactivitymanager-class-in-android-issue)

This is working fine for me.

Comment: Can you tell where to use this method appropriately, i tried but didn`t found the right way to call

Answer (score 0):

You have made this complex. I would prefer something like this for sake of simplicity.

TabActivity -> Tab1 Activity, Tab2 Activity and Tab3 Activity

For the Tab2 Activity you can use ViewAnimator if the requirement is to show different screens.

For the above question, you need to look into where your onBackPressed event is getting propogated and handled. The way you have done it could be any of the activity or TabGroupActivity or parent TabActivity.

Comment: hi Pravin i cant use ViewAnimater here. the only problem im facing is im not able to set the correct flags to restart and resume the Activities.

Comment: public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {

            Window window;
            Log.e("startChildActivity","startChildActivity");

                window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP ));

                if (window != null) 
                {
                    mIdList.add(Id);

                    setContentView(window.getDecorView());
                }


        }