# In ActivityGroup, how to restore the previous activity(without restarting)

Tags: android

I have an ActivityGroup which has 4 activities in a Tab.

A1->A2->A3->A4

Suppose i press back from any activity the previous activity is being restarted. my requirement when i call a new Activity it should be started fresh. and when i press the back button , the previous activity has to be restored(without restarting).

Please help me on this . im lacking in setting appropriate Intent Flags. my code goes like this.

```
      public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {

        Window window;
        Log.e("startChildActivity","startChildActivity");

            window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

            if (window != null) 
            {
                mIdList.add(Id);

                setContentView(window.getDecorView());
            }


    } 


        public void finishFromChild(Activity child) 
    {
        restartFlag=true;

        Log.e("finishFromChild","finishFromChild");
        LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();

        int index = mIdList.size()-1;

        if (index < 1) {

            finish();

            return;
        }

        manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);

        mIdList.remove(index);

        index--;

        String lastId = mIdList.get(index);

        Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();

        Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I finaly got a solution for this . actually the culprit is

```
   manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
```

in the code.

there is a bug in Android destroyActivity() function impl .

The exact source of the problem is in the following chunk of code in LocalActivityManager.java:

```
public Window destroyActivity(String id, boolean finish) {
    LocalActivityRecord r = mActivities.get(id);
    Window win = null;
    if (r != null) {
        win = performDestroy(r, finish);
        if (finish) {
            mActivities.remove(r);
        }
    }
    return win;
}
```

The variable mActivities is the hashmap containing the activity records and it uses the id passed into startActivity() as the key. In this method, the object passed in for the key is a LocalActivityRecord instead of the id string. This results in the hashmap not finding the entry and thus not removing it.

More info refer this link. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=879More

Comment: Yes it is bug then whats the solution of it ?

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the line

```
Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId,lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

with

```
Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
```

Comment: Providing a solution is good ; explaining in the answer is better

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i advise you to read this article: [Tasks and Back Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) very carefully. And try to understand how the different launchModes and intent flags work.

Now to answer your question, there is nothing you can do if the OS decides to kill your activity for you. Basically, your activity will be in the onPause() state as soon as another activity comes on top of it. Then if the OS decides that it's running out of memory (among other things), it will call move it to onDestroy(). No amount of intent flags can change this behavior for you. So from what you describe above, it seems that your activity was one of the unlucky ones selected to be destroyed after it was put in onPause().

So... what can you do to fix your problem? This is what you should do:

You should implement `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in your activity to save and restore all the state information that you needed the next time your activity opens in `onCreate()` you should check the `Bundle` object passed on to you and try to rebuild your activity with the savedState information passed to you.

I also advise you to read this ref doc about [Saving Activity State](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState) very carefully as well