# destroyActivity() Bug in LocalActivityManager class in Android issue

Tags: android

I have a Tab Activity and with in Tab, im using Activity Group. and using LocalActivityManger,
im trying to destroy an Activty using the following function call provided in LocalActivityManger class

```
               manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
```

in the code. but later i found that there is a bug in Android impl for this

The exact source of the problem is in the following chunk of code in LocalActivityManager.java:

```
public Window destroyActivity(String id, boolean finish) {
LocalActivityRecord r = mActivities.get(id);
Window win = null;
if (r != null) {
    win = performDestroy(r, finish);
    if (finish) {
        mActivities.remove(r);
    }
}
return win;
```

}
The variable mActivities is the hashmap containing the activity records and it uses the id passed into startActivity() as the key. In this method, the object passed in for the key is a LocalActivityRecord instead of the id string. This results in the hashmap not finding the entry and thus not removing it.

More info refer this link. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=879More

**and i found a work around for this issue and im using following function to fix the problem.**

```
       public boolean destroy(String id) {

        if(manager != null){
            manager.destroyActivity(id, false);
            try {
                final Field mActivitiesField = LocalActivityManager.class.getDeclaredField("mActivities");
                if(mActivitiesField != null){
                    mActivitiesField.setAccessible(true);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final Map<String, Object> mActivities = (Map<String, Object>)mActivitiesField.get(manager);
                    if(mActivities != null){
                        mActivities.remove(id);
                    }
                    final Field mActivityArrayField = LocalActivityManager.class.getDeclaredField("mActivityArray");
                    if(mActivityArrayField != null){
                        mActivityArrayField.setAccessible(true);
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        final ArrayList<Object> mActivityArray = (ArrayList<Object>)mActivityArrayField.get(manager);
                        if(mActivityArray != null){
                            for(Object record : mActivityArray){
                                final Field idField = record.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
                                if(idField != null){
                                    idField.setAccessible(true);
                                    final String _id = (String)idField.get(record);
                                    if(id.equals(_id)){
                                        mActivityArray.remove(record);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**now the problem is, this fix is working fine in Android API versions 2.1,2.2 and 2.3 but i tested in 3.0 . but it is failing there. no exceptions.**

**I want to know in which API version this bug has been fixed.**

**And also what fix can i make for this so that it will work fine in all the API versions after 2.1 .**

Thank u

Comment: can u tell me where we have to use this method.

Comment: Hi karthi , you should use this method from finishFromChild() method                    @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
 
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
      int index = mIdList.size()-1;
      if (index < 1) {
          finish();
          return;
      } 
destroy(mIdList.get(index), manager);(<--here->)
mIdList.remove(index); index--;
String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
  }

Comment: I have pasted the method finishFromChild(Activity child) try using it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but like as you specified i implement that code, but still onCreate executed twice, version:2.1. Can u help me out.

Comment: http://pastie.org/3486293 refer this site, i posted tab group activity class code.